# plotting realtime data and turning on and off data series using flot api

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

I am using flot charts. I want to plot chart which is updated per second and also want to add the feature of turning off and on the data series.
I am able to make it work but has problems which I did not expect, like color of one series  change when other series is turned off; other is when I update the array of data series the charts seems to move but it removes element from the right,at the same time the new value is plotted on the right hand side ...

```
    var d1 = [] ;
    var d2 = [] ;
    var d3 = [] ;


$(function(){



    {%for reading in readings%}
            var time_stamp = parseFloat({{reading['timestamp']}} + 19800.00) * 1000
            var A = parseFloat({{reading['values']['A']}})  ;
            var V = parseFloat({{reading['values']['VLN']}}) - 50 ;
            var W = parseFloat({{reading['values']['W']}}) / 1000 ;

            d1.push([time_stamp,A]);
            d2.push([time_stamp,V]);
            d3.push([time_stamp,W]);
    {%endfor%}

    var datasets = {
                "current":{
                        label : "A",
                        data : d1
                },
                "voltage":{
                    label : "V",
                    data : d2
                },
                "power":{
                    label : "W",
                    data : d3
                },


    }


    var i = 0;
        $.each(datasets, function(key, val) {
            val.color = i;
            ++i;
    });



    // insert checkboxes 
    var choiceContainer = $("#choices");
    $.each(datasets, function(key, val) {
        choiceContainer.append("<br/><input type='checkbox' name='" + key +
            "' checked='checked' id='id" + key + "'></input>" +
            "<label for='id" + key + "'>"
            + val.label + "</label>");
    });


    choiceContainer.find("input").click(plotAccordingToChoices);

    function plotAccordingToChoices() {


            var data = [];

            choiceContainer.find("input:checked").each(function () {
                var key = $(this).attr("name");
                if (key && datasets[key]) {

                    data.push(datasets[key]);
                }
            });

            if (data.length > 0) {
                $.plot("#placeholder", data, {
                    series: {
                        shadowSize: 0,
                        lines: {
                            show: true
                        },

                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        min: 0
                    },
                    xaxis: {
                        tickDecimals: 0,
                        mode:"time"
                    }
                });
            }


            setTimeout(getNextDataset,1000);

        }



        plotAccordingToChoices();

});

function getNextDataset()
        {

            $.ajax({url : '/newdata' , success:function(result){
                    reading =JSON.parse(result);
                    var time_stamp = (parseFloat(reading.timestamp) + 19800.00) * 1000
                    var A = parseFloat(reading.values.A) ;
                    var W = parseFloat(reading.values.W) / 1000 ;
                    var V = parseFloat(reading.values.VLN) - 50 ;

                    d1.shift();d2.shift();d3.shift();

                    d1.push([time_stamp,A]);
                    d2.push([time_stamp,V]);
                    d3.push([time_stamp,W]);


                    var datasets = {
                                "current":{
                                        label : "A",
                                        data : d1
                                },
                                "voltage":{
                                    label : "V",
                                    data : d2
                                },
                                "power":{
                                    label : "W",
                                    data : d3
                                },
                    }


                    var data = [] ;
                    var choiceContainer = $("#choices");
                    choiceContainer.find("input:checked").each(function () {
                        var key = $(this).attr("name");
                        if (key && datasets[key]) {

                            data.push(datasets[key]);
                        }
                    });


                    if (data.length > 0) {

                        $.plot("#placeholder", data, {
                            series: {
                                shadowSize: 0,
                                lines: {
                                    show: true
                                },
                                points:{
                                    show:false
                                },

                            },
                            yaxis: {
                                min: 0
                            },
                            xaxis: {
                                tickDecimals: 0,
                                mode:"time"
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
            });

            setTimeout(getNextDataset,1000) ;
        }
```

`

I am making use of code available in flot charts examples.Where am I going wrong ??
Thank you ?

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1 :  Color updating every time a checkbox was checked or unchecked
Reason: Every time the checkbox click event was triggered,some how the color used to get updated
Solution :  Removed  setTimeout(getNextDataset,1000); call from the function plotAccordingToChoices()

---

Problem 2:  The data elements are removed from the right instead of left.
Reason :  (Very dumb) Data was coming in descending order and I was using pushing data in that order only.So latest point was at location 0 of the array and oldest point was at location n-1.And I was removing (n-1)th point.
Solution : Replaced push in the beginning with unshift().Did the magic :P

Comment: I didn't read it thoroughly enough, but I think the problem with the color is that you use the right technique initially, explicitly assigning a color to each dataset, but you don't do it inside the Ajax call, which creates new datasets (you may want to avoid that repetition in the code) and does not assign colors.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida : Yes, I have kept it outside the ajax call, only once.It is working correctly.